# send retrofit get request with no key for value

Tags: java, android, android-studio, get, retrofit

I'm trying to make simple get request using retrofit which work on this URL **example.com/product_barcode/12345678997455** but when I use it like this way

```
public interface Api {
    @GET(PRODUCT_BARCODE)
    public Single<Data> getProductData(@QueryName String barcode);

}
```

I got 404 error because the link be like that **example.com/product_barcode/?12345678997455**

how I use retrofit to get the request path without sign ? before barcode

Comment: Wich framework do you use ? Spring mvc, jersey, other ?

Comment: I'm android developer

Comment: Do you want to access an existing API or build one ?

Comment: just access one

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do it like this

```
@GET("example.com/product_barcode/{barcode}")
Single<Data> getProductData(@Path("barcode") String barcode);
```